# Detener prompt cuando el número no sea igual al valor de este Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo esta simple calculadora con prompts y tengo el siguiente problema:

Cuando el valor del prompt no sea igual a 1, 2, 3 y 4, debe dejar de mostrarme el mensaje pidiendo que ingrese números para operar, creo que esto se debe a que muestro las variables `primer_valor` y `segundo_valor` fuera del `if` y de los `else if` adyacentes, y dentro del bloque `else if (select_operation===...)` en el que también hay un `else` donde muestra una alerta, por eso es que primero se muestra el prompt y luego la alerta.

Una solución a esto es establecer varios *prompts* en cada `if` y `else if` donde te pida algo como: *Ingrese primer número para sumar, restar*, etc.

Pero no quiero establecer varios prompt, solo dos propmt al principio y luego operar sus valores.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('iniciar-calculadora');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calculatorInit();
});

const calculatorInit = () => {

    alert('Iniciando calculadora....');
    alert('Por favor selecciona un número:');

    var select_operation = prompt("1. Suma 2. Resta 3. Multiplicación 4. División");

    if (select_operation === '') {

        alert('Por favor ingrese un número');
        alert('La calculadora se reiniciará....')

        return calculatorInit();

    } else if (select_operation) {

        var primer_valor = parseInt(prompt('Ingrese el primer número para operar')),
            segundo_valor = parseInt(prompt('Ingrese el segundo número para operar'));

        if (select_operation === '1') {
            alert(`La suma de ${primer_valor} y ${segundo_valor} es ${primer_valor + segundo_valor}`);
        } else if (select_operation === '2') {
            alert(`La resta de ${primer_valor} y ${segundo_valor} es ${primer_valor - segundo_valor}`);
        } else if (select_operation === '3') {
            alert(`La multiplicación de ${primer_valor} y ${segundo_valor} es ${primer_valor * segundo_valor}`);
        } else if (select_operation === '4') {
            alert(`La división entre ${primer_valor} y ${segundo_valor} es ${primer_valor / segundo_valor}`);
        } else {

            primer_valor, segundo_valor = null;
            alert('No es un número válido');
        }
    } else {
        alert('Cerrando calculadora....');
    }
}
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#iniciar-calculadora{
  padding: 0 45px;
  line-height: 3.5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  background: rgba(76,26,36,1);
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#iniciar-calculadora:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}
#iniciar-calculadora:active{
  transform: scale(0.85);
}
```

```html
<button id="iniciar-calculadora">Iniciar calculadora</button>
```

Además tengo una duda, porque no puedo retornar la variable `select_operation` para volver a preguntar el tipo de operación a ejecutar, he retornado la `function calculatorInit()` para volver a iniciar la función, si quiero solo retornar la variable ¿Cómo hago para que me retorne `select_operation` para no ejecutar de nuevo la función?.

Volviendo a la pregunta principal, ¿Cómo evitar que se muestre ambos prompt cuando ejecuto la `alert('No es un número válido')`?.

Comment: te falta evaluar `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes extender la condición donde compruebas si se ha elegido una operación:

```
if (select_operation === ''){
```

Tiene que quedar así:

```javascript
//Obtenemos la operación seleccionada convertida da número, si no ingresa nada o ingresa un texto ponemos por defecto -1
select_operation = !isNaN(select_operation) ? parseInt(select_operation): -1;

//Si no está entre [1-4] muestra los mensajes para solicitar una opción válida
if (select_operation < 1 || select_operation > 4){
        alert("Ingresa una opción válida");
        alert('La calculadora se reiniciará....');

        return calculatorInit();
}
```

Comment: tu respuesta es de gran ayuda, pude resolver el problema con la propuesta que me das, también lo resolví de otra manera, agregando esta condicion  if(select_operation >= 1 && select_operation <= 4){ <------------ dentro de ------------->   else if (select_operation){ , devuelve false cuando no es 1 - 4